# How to change the checkbox values what is there inside a map function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, checkbox, react-hooks

I need to update the checkbox values which is been rendered from an API,

Ex:-

```
data?.map((option) => {
return (
  <Checkbox 
     checked = {option?.suppressed == true ? false : true}
     onChange={(e) => handleChange({
         value:e.target.checked, 
         modifierId:item.id,
         optionId:option?.modifier_option_id,
     })}
  />
})
```

In this the checkbox values is changing from true to false but I am unable to see the changes in the front end.

EX:- If I click on the checkbox and if it is true the style doesn't changes. (it will display as checked until I click save and re-render the API)

Answer (score 0):

you have to store data in a state in React and the update state when checkbox onChange trigger

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

const fetchData = (data)=>{
      setData(data)
}

data?.map((option) => {
return (
  <Checkbox 
     checked = {option?.suppressed === true ? false : true}
     onChange={(e) => setData(prev=>{
        return prev.map(item=>{
         if(option.id === item.id) {
            item.suppressed = e.target.checked
         }
         return item 
        })
     })}
  />
})
```

I hope this may solve your problem